# How to implement Wordpress' the_permalink(); into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to implement the Wordpress permalink function `the_permalink();` into a Javascript script which should display a social bar with a top button on the mobile view of my website.

The following script works except the permalink function which doesn't show the right URL if I click on the Twitter button. It only shows  on the share screen.

How can I do it work?

```
jQuery(function ($) {

// Der Button wird mit JavaScript erzeugt und vor dem Ende des body eingebunden.
var back_to_top_button = ['<a href="#top" class="back-to-top"><span class="fawesome fa fa-chevron-up"></span><br/>Top</a><!-- Sharebar --><div class="sharerbar"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<?php the_title(); ?>&url=<?php the_permalink();?>&utm_source=twsharebutton" onclick="if( typeof ga != "undefined" ) { var ts = ga.getAll(); for (var i=0; i < ts.length; ++i) { var t = ts[i]; ga(t.get("name")+".send","event","Sharebar","click","Twitter",1); } } if( typeof _gaq_trackers != "undefined" ) { for (var i=0; i < _gaq_trackers.length; ++i) { var t = _gaq_trackers[i]; _gaq.push([t+"._trackEvent","Sharebar","click","Twitter",1]); } } ;" class="sblink sblinktw" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/80f4511a15.js" async></script></div><!-- Sharebar -->'].join("");
$("body").append(back_to_top_button)

// Der Button wird ausgeblendet
$(".back-to-top").hide();
$(".sharerbar").hide();

// Funktion für das Scroll-Verhalten
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { // Wenn 100 Pixel gescrolled wurde
            $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
            /*$('.sharerbar').fadeIn();*/
        } else {
            $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
            /*$('.sharerbar').fadeOut();*/
        }
    });

    $('.back-to-top').click(function () { // Klick auf den Button
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are making the PHP code into a string. You could do something like this.

```
var title = <?php the_title(); ?>;
var permalink = <?php the_permalink(); ?>;

var back_to_top_button = ['<a href="#top" class="back-to-top"><span class="fawesome fa fa-chevron-up"></span><br/>Top</a><!-- Sharebar --><div class="sharerbar"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+ title +'&url='+ permalink +'&utm_source=twsharebutton" onclick="if( typeof ga != "undefined" ) { var ts = ga.getAll(); for (var i=0; i < ts.length; ++i) { var t = ts[i]; ga(t.get("name")+".send","event","Sharebar","click","Twitter",1); } } if( typeof _gaq_trackers != "undefined" ) { for (var i=0; i < _gaq_trackers.length; ++i) { var t = _gaq_trackers[i]; _gaq.push([t+"._trackEvent","Sharebar","click","Twitter",1]); } } ;" class="sblink sblinktw" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/80f4511a15.js" async></script></div><!-- Sharebar -->']
```

Note: this will only work if it is JS on the page you are wanting to load `the_title()` on. If you want to run this in a separate JS file, you'll need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code. Please try it. I hope it will work for you.

```
 jQuery(function ($) {

        var the_title = "<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>";
        var the_permlink = "<?php echo get_the_permalink();?>";

        // Der Button wird mit JavaScript erzeugt und vor dem Ende des body eingebunden.
        var back_to_top_button = ['<a href="#top" class="back-to-top"><span class="fawesome fa fa-chevron-up"></span><br/>Top</a><!-- Sharebar --><div class="sharerbar"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+the_title+'&url='+the_permlink+'&utm_source=twsharebutton" onclick="if( typeof ga != "undefined" ) { var ts = ga.getAll(); for (var i=0; i < ts.length; ++i) { var t = ts[i]; ga(t.get("name")+".send","event","Sharebar","click","Twitter",1); } } if( typeof _gaq_trackers != "undefined" ) { for (var i=0; i < _gaq_trackers.length; ++i) { var t = _gaq_trackers[i]; _gaq.push([t+"._trackEvent","Sharebar","click","Twitter",1]); } } ;" class="sblink sblinktw" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/80f4511a15.js" async></script></div><!-- Sharebar -->'].join("");
        $("body").append(back_to_top_button)

        // Der Button wird ausgeblendet
        $(".back-to-top").hide();
        $(".sharerbar").hide();

        // Funktion für das Scroll-Verhalten
        $(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) { // Wenn 100 Pixel gescrolled wurde
                    $('.back-to-top').fadeIn();
                    /*$('.sharerbar').fadeIn();*/
                } else {
                    $('.back-to-top').fadeOut();
                    /*$('.sharerbar').fadeOut();*/
                }
            });

            $('.back-to-top').click(function () { // Klick auf den Button
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 800);
                return false;
            });
        });

        });
```

**Note:**   `the_title()` and `the_permalink()` work inside the loop only.